# searching inside dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I'm working with python an a dictionaries that I have not able to solve it. I'm working with a dictionaries. I'm trying search every element of the the dictionary `words` inside all medias.items() and then four print it out lines, two for `medias[0]` and two for `medias[1]`. Is there something I made wrong? Any idea to fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}


def count_words(url, the_word):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.text.lower().count(the_word)

def main():
  #  url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
    medias = {
        'Los Angeles Times': ['http://www.latimes.com/'],
        'New York Times': ['http://www.nytimes.com/']
    }

    word = 'trump'
    words = ['Trump', 'Facebook']

    print('--- Iniciando ---')
    print('Hora: ', time.strftime("%X"))
    for web_name, urls in medias.items():
        for url in urls:
            count = count_words(url, words)
            print('La palabra {} aparece {} veces en el sitio del {}.'.format(words, count, web_name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please reduce that to a [mre] - for the purpose of the question (if I understand correctly) the web scraping is not relevant. Your mre can be a toy example including data and code that faithfully illustrates your problem. We shouldn't have to access *offsite* resouces to obtain the data that you are having trouble working with.

Comment: You haven't stated what is wrong with your solution. How is it deficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few errors that I fixed within your code:

First, you forgot to loop through your array when using your words, so I added a for loop at the very end of your code to loop through those words.

Secondly, after I did that your code was returning zero so I added .lower() to each word within count_words and then it worked.

```py
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}


def count_words(url, the_word):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.text.lower().count(the_word.lower())

def main():
  #  url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
    medias = {
        'Los Angeles Times': ['http://www.latimes.com/'],
        'New York Times': ['http://www.nytimes.com/']
    }

    word = 'trump'
    words = ['Trump', 'Facebook']

    print('--- Iniciando ---')
    print('Hora: ', time.strftime("%X"))
    for web_name, urls in medias.items():
        for url in urls:
            for word in words:
                count = count_words(url, word)
                print('La palabra {} aparece {} veces en el sitio del {}.'.format(word, count, web_name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for web_name, urls in medias.items():
        for url in urls:
            for word in words:
                count = count_words(url, word)
                print('La palabra {} aparece {} veces en el sitio del {}.'.format(word, count, web_name))
```

You passed a list, whereas you should pass a word to `count` function.